# Implementation of AdMob ads in Cordova

Tags: javascript, html, css, admob

I have a problem with the implementation of ads from the AdMob platform to my application written using the Cordova framework. At the beginning I installed the cordova-admob plugin. And I've pasted the code below into the index.js file. After compiling the application to the android version, no ads appear. Please help.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

// Set AdMobAds options:
admob.setOptions({
    publisherId: "MY APP ID", // Required
    interstitialAdId: "MY AD ID" // Optional
});

// Start showing banners (atomatic when autoShowBanner is set to true)
admob.createBannerView();

// Request interstitial (will present automatically when autoShowInterstitial is set to true)
admob.requestInterstitialAd();
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

Comment: it does not work any further :(